# Is my explanation correct regarding Maximum value of Sine function over $\Bbb C$?

Tags: complex-analysis, functions, trigonometry, analyticity

Question: What is the maximum value of sine function taking domain as $\Bbb C$?

My answer is: The maximum value is not defined.

Explanation: Since the range of sine function is $\Bbb C$ and $\Bbb C$ is not well ordered, hence the maximum value of sine function can not be defined.

Comment: What's the original wording of the question? I assume it asks for the maximum of $|\sin(z)|$. This should probably show that there are holomorphic functions that are bounded on $\mathbb{R}$, but unbounded in $\mathbb{C}$ - or alternatively you should justify that $\sin(x)$ is not a counterexample for the maximum principle.

Comment: @Dominik I updated the details of my query.

Answer (score 1):

Your reasoning is clearly wrong. You could say the same thing for practically all nonreal-valued function. When someone is asking for the maximum of a nonreal-valued object, it is implied that you have to consider the absolute value (or, more generally, some kind of norm).

The proof that $\sin z$ is unbounded on $\mathbb C$ can be traced as follows (there might be some wrong sign! Check it!). By definition,

$$\sin z = \frac{e^{iz} - e^{-iz}}{2i}.$$

Now, set $z = x + iy$ (with $x,y \in \mathbb R$):

$$e^{iz} = e^{ix - y}, \quad e^{-iz} = e^{-ix + y}.$$

Hence, using the De Moivre formula and making some simple algebraic manipulations,

$$\sin z = -i \cos x \sinh y + \sin x \cosh y.$$

So we have

$$\vert {\sin z} \vert^2 = \sinh^2 y + \sin^2 x. $$

Hyperbolic sine is obviously unbounded on $\mathbb R$, while sine is bounded, hence also $\sin z$ is unbounded on $\mathbb C$.

Comment: You could say it for real valued functions too because $\mathbb R$ is not well ordered either. In that case it's wrong in every sense for the sine function.

Comment: @Federico Thanks. I understand Sine is unbounded over $\Bbb C$. But what can then be my answer if the asker is not asking about norm or absolute value?

Comment: @MattSamuel  I used the word "ordered" in the sense that values of the function are in $\Bbb C$ so we can not say which one is greater or which one is smaller. Apologies from me if I am using wrong terminologies since I am a bit weaker in Set theory.

Comment: @Vikrant In a well ordered set, every subset has a least element. This is not true for the real numbers. The real numbers are ordered, but not well ordered.

Comment: @VikrantDesai I'm not aware of a notion of "maximum" not involving some kind of relation $\leq$, that is defined in natural way for real numbers. The most reasonable type of $\leq$ relation in $\mathbb C$ or generally in a normed space is obtained by taking the norm, in order to deal with real numbers. However, at least in principle, one could set a different rule for comparison of complex numbers (I can't find a consistent one at the moment) but, in that case, such a rule must be specified.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**: Since *sin*z is entire hence by Picard's little theorem, it must assume all values on complex plane *C* with at most one possible exception.

Comment: So the maximum value is infinity? Actually I am very much concerned about not getting to decide whether a certain complex number is greater than the other or not(like $i$ is neither greater nor less than $1+i$). Can we say that (say)$5+2i \lt \infty$? I am still getting myself introduced to this subject so have some difficulties.

Comment: complex numbers are not compared in that sense as you are thinking. Rather we compare their modulii.